# open tensorboard in Google Chrome shows blank

Tags: tensorboard

My tensorflow is installed on ubuntu 16.04 and also generates log files, but when running tensorboard there is nothing on Google Chrome. There was no error on the command line.

[image: tensorboard_message]

This error only appears on Google Chrome. What can I do to display it properly?

[image: google_Chrome_message]

> This file is deprecated. Please use
>   `iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html`, and one of the
>   specific dom-modules instead
>
> thinkpad/:39507 This file is deprecated. Please use
>   `iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html`, and one of the
>   specific dom-modules instead
>
> thinkpad/:157058 Uncaught TypeError: Object.values is not a function

Comment: 谁可以帮下我啊~求救   !  Who can help me  help !

Comment: I guess new changes to chrome broke polymer 1x and 2x websites, you could refer to this blog https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2017-10-18-upcoming-changes which also explain why it's not working only in chrome. Try updating you versions

Comment: I just mailed out a change rolling forward TensorBoard's Polymer dependencies too. We can cherry-pick it onto old release branches as well. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/pull/1090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you're using Chrome version 49 or earlier: https://caniuse.com/#search=object.value

I mailed out [tensorflow/tensorboard#1089](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/pull/1089) to solve this problem. Please note there might be other things in our codebase that are incompatible with old browsers. I'd like to improve this situation. Please email jart@google.com if you encounter similar problems.

It especially helps if you can send a screenshot of the code in question. For example, if Chrome says JavaScript broke on line 48238, you can run `wget -O index.html http://localhost:6006/` and `nano +48238 index.html` so you can take a screenshot of the code in question. (Note: This will get easier in the future.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I uninstalled the  version 49 and installed the  version 59 of Google Chrome. When it is running again, it will display normally!